# attach jquery array to form submit

Tags: jquery, post, form-submit, onsubmit

I am using the following to submit a form on button click.  I need to attach an array named 'selected' to this post as well.  I cannot use ajax for this because there will be a download happening on the posting page.  I need this array to process the file to be downloaded.

I did some searching and came upon this, but was not able to get it working either :

```
var input = $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"selected"}).val(selected);
$('#test').append(input);
```

Current :

```
var selected = [1,2,54,56,23]; // could be anything

$('#test').submit(function(event) {
    if (selected.length > 0)
    {
        $('#test').attr('action','/process/p_screenshots_download2.php');
        $('#test').attr('type','post');
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('#test').submit(function(event) {
    $.each(selected, function(i, v){
        var input = $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"selected[]"}).val(v);
        $('#test').append(input);    
    });
    if (selected.length > 0)
    {
        $('#test').prop('action','/process/p_screenshots_download2.php');
        $('#test').prop('method','POST');
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

this will add a set of hidden inputs with the values in the array to the form before it submits.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either... I get something along the lines of ...php?selected[]=1609449&selected[]=4697 and doing a var_dump( $_POST['selected']); returns NULL.

Comment: @user756659 What's the action of your form? is it `GET` or `POST`

Comment: $('#test').attr('type','post');

Comment: Just realized that was the problem - $('#test').attr('method','post');  Seems to be working properly now.

Comment: @user756659 use prop instead of attr `$('#test').prop('method','POST');` or just set it to post in the html.

Comment: Same for action as well?  Is prop the preferred way or is there another reason?

Comment: @user756659 yes. `prop` changes the current state while attr changes the initial state of the element. Also why are you changing it in js instead of having it how its needed on the form's html?

Comment: No particular reason other than the entire form and button is added into the dom by jquery... just did it this way.